# The message "Connection test failed: Password authentication failed for user "postgres"" was displayed

Tags: postgresql, strapi

I want to install the postgres version of strapi, a headless CMS for use with Gatsby.js.
However, I get the following message and cannot install it.

npx create-strapi-app@3.6.8
↓

```
Choose your installation type Custom (manual settings)
? Would you like to use a template? (Templates are Strapi configurations designe
d for a specific use case) >No
? Choose your default database client> postgres
? Database name: strapiapi
? Host: 127.0.0.1
? Port: 5432
? Username: postgres
? Password: ********
? Enable SSL connection: No

⛔️ Connection test failed: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

pgAdmin already installed
I followed the instructions in this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FeZyCxwb1aQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common error faced with PostgreSQL installation.

How I fixed it was by changing the port number from 5432 to 5433

Maybe try this?
While making a server from the pgAdmin, make the changes to the port number.

Changing it to 5433 worked for me.
If it still doesn't work, you might will have to reinstall the RDBMS into some other directory and then try connecting.

Comment: responce is ⛔️ Connection test failed: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5433